# Using Vue2, how to bind html element attribute to the property of a variable

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using Vue 2, How do I bind to javascript in an html element attribute?

For example, I'd like to assign a `colspan` attribute dynamically to the javasript length property value of my data `columns`.

Instead of this:

```
<td colspan="4">
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<td :colspan="{ columns.length }">
```

Comment: You're almost there: `<td :colspan="columns.length">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't need to specify brackets. Just do this:

```
<td :colspan="columns.length">
```

See the [Vue documentation for Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html).

Comment: Jeez.  I'm sure I did that already.  I must have had an unnoticed typo :-/